# Emoji Keyboard in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, emoji

Is it possible to display emoji Keyboard in Asp.net?

Actually we have a Chat Application like Whatsapp for Mobiles.
We are sending Admin Messages from Website.
We will write some text on TextBox in website and send that to everyone.
In that TextBox,I want to implement Smileys also.
So,For that we need to save Unicode values to TextBox like this :

So,I've found one website which gives this requirement (http://www.iemoji.com/)

I've tried to copy the scripts and css from their page but unable to get the functionality.
I'm just able to get the design.

Comment: Provide [relevant code](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). The answer to your question is `yes`, but I don't that the question asked is what you wanted answered.

Comment: is there a way to attach project here?
because my code is full of scripts and css files

Comment: No, and you should not just dump all your code here. Instead, read the link I provided in my first comment.